# Convert entire List which contains Dataframe as List Items to single Dataframe, Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am using below script in Multiprocessing Task:

```
Data_List = pool.map(self.Get_Series_Data, Series_Id_List)
```

Method "self.Get_Series_Data", generates Dataframe and "pool.map" stores as List in Data_List

```
[
Date      Value    Series_Id
0 1985-01-01  106.92593  CANEPUINDXM
1 1985-02-01  114.69938  CANEPUINDXM,

Date      Value    Series_Id
0 1995-01-01  192.91191  CHIEPUINDXM
1 1995-02-01  193.98785  CHIEPUINDXM,

Date      Value   Series_Id
0 1993-01-01  178.75275  DEEPUINDXM
1 1993-02-01  114.21303  DEEPUINDXM,

Date     Value   Series_Id
0 1987-01-01  57.10735  EUEPUINDXM
1 1987-02-01  49.24059  EUEPUINDXM,

Date     Value  Series_Id
0 1987-01-01  69.95834  FREUINDXM
1 1987-02-01  60.32132  FREUINDXM
]
```

I want to convert this list items(contains dataframe) to single Dataframe

Comment: `single_dataframe=pd.concat(data_list)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work :-

`single_dataframe = pd.concat(data_list)`